# Eclipse Mars reacts delayed and crashes on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

I´ve changed from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 recently and when I'm running Eclipse Mars 2 (4.5.2), it reacts really slow or delayed. When I try to do anything like creating a new project, importing or just open the "about Eclipse" window, nothing is happening for a couple of seconds. When finally for example the import dialog finally shows up, eclipse hangs at the following steps when I want to choose e.g. the folder from where things should be imported. The only operation for me is to cancel the application and restart. During those operations the CPU usage seems to be normal, which means not 100% of utilization. It doesn't seem like the machine is working on a lot of stuff in the background (since I´m running no other applications than firefox), it rather feels like if you have a extremely bad ping in an online game. Other applications are working quite normal.

My system: intel i5 cpu 2,50ghz, 4gb ram

I did not download an installer, just the official latest 64bit *.tar.gz file. Then I extracted it to `/user/home/Eclipse` and ran the application without installation.

Did someone else face these issues? How can I check if maybe some basic drivers for my system are missing?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/761680/384631). Including the same answer here.

Type `export SWT_GTK3=0`in the terminal and start eclipse.

If that works, then a more persistent fix is to put the 2 lines in italics below into eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before the line:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

Answer (score 0):

~/.profile
add:
export SWT_GTK3=0

Comment: 1 out of 10 for effort ;-)  Can you elaborate on that? What is it suppose to do?